# Galaxy Nexus does not charge when turned on

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-nexus, charging

Galaxy Nexus does not charge when powered **on**, but it charges properly when powered **off**. Phone doesn't detect USB connection also. This happened without any reason. Phone is not rooted.

Tried different cable, charger, everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds to me like a hardware issue. If you're still under warranty, I'd get it repaired. If not, you'll have to decide whether you want to live with it or pay for repair (or replace the phone).

Comment: @forums,@Scott: I am able to charge using a 2A charger even when turned on. So is it not a hardware related issue?Any idea ?

Comment: That sounds to me even more like a hardware issue, as I can't imagine that the software would care or even know about the charger's amperage.

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to be using a 3rd party charger?

500mAh chargers cannot charge the Nexus while on, 1Ah chargers can but might struggle. I recommend chargers with 1.5Ah for charging high-end devices

Alternatively, the problem might lie with the power management of your ROM. Have you also installed an app recently before this happened?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried different charger with 1.5A also.I have not installed any app, I just flashed to new 4.2.2 JB image. But after seeing the issue flashed back to 4.2.1. Still issue persists.My main issue is not getting charged, USB is not detecting. I can charge device with turned off.

Comment: It might also be a kernel problem (if it's custom made). Honestly I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Thanks.I am not sure, even i tried stock images from google.

Comment: @Rilwan: Your question says that the phone isn't rooted, but here you mention that you've flashed a custom ROM. That's important information that should be in your question.

Comment: @user267:I flashed a custom ROM(rooted one) then flashed back stock ROM. That's why i did not mention rooted.

Comment: I don't think amperage of the charger matters. I have a 2.5A charger from Targus. It still does the same thing. It is worth mentioning that at the beginning, the symptom was slowly developed. At the beginning, the phone can occasionally be charged while powered on, if you plug and un-plug the cords many times. Later, it basically completely stopped being charged at all.